# How add image to image in OpenCv c++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, addition

I load small image.

```
 Mat extra;
 extra = imread("Korona.jpg");
```

I load image from camera and I try add my image.

```
VideoCapture cap;
Mat frame;
cap >> frame;
cv::Rect roi(cv::Point(0, 0), cv::Size(110, 110));
cv::Mat destinationROI = img(roi);
extra.copyTo(destinationROI(cv::Rect(0, 0, extra.cols, extra.rows)));
```

But not successful and have this error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x
>   + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat, file
>   C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp,
>   line 522

Any ideas? Thx.

Comment: the error indicates that your `roi` dimensions are larger than the source `Mat` what is the size of the read in jpg?

Comment: extra.copyTo(img(cv::Rect(5, 5, 11, 11))); i Try this but have this error penCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 9716

Comment: What is `img`? The declaration is not in your code...

Answer (score 2):

```
if(roi.x >= 0 && roi.y >= 0 && roi.width + roi.x < input_frame.cols && roi.height + roi.y < input_frame.rows)
{
    // your code

}
else
    return -1;
```

Found similar issues and pulled code from [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/21374/possible-solutions-for-opencv-assertion-error-problem/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29717783/8155481)

Looking at your code, looks like you don't open your capture

```
VideoCapture cap(0); //for a webcam
Mat frame;
if(cap.isOpened())
   cap >> frame;
else
   throw;
cv::Rect roi(cv::Point(0, 0), cv::Size(110, 110));
cv::Mat destinationROI = frame(roi);
extra.copyTo(destinationROI(cv::Rect(0, 0, extra.cols, extra.rows)));
```

Check out OpenCV's [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html) on VideoCapture to make sure you're getting that done correctly.