# iOS app crashing while scanning passport MRZ

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

The app is crashing while I am trying to scan the MRZ code on the passport. **This is the log:**

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in Mat, file ../matrix.cpp, line 517
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: ../matrix.cpp:517: error: (-215) 0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows in function Mat

**Here is the stack trace:**

> **#12 0x0062662c in cv::Mat::operator()(cv::Rect_ const&) const**
>  
>   **#13   0x00628c72 in ::-[PassportScanner realProcessImage:](cv::Mat &)**

Contents of the above function are as follows:

```
Mat Mat::operator()( const Rect& roi ) const
{
    return Mat(*this, roi);
} 

-(void) realProcessImage:(cv::Mat &)cropped {

    //Some other code

    vector<cv::Rect> rotatedRegions = [self show:cropped gray:rotated2];

    // Sort by y
    std::sort(rotatedRegions.begin(), rotatedRegions.end(), sortByBoundingRectYPosition);

    if (rotatedRegions.size() == 2) {
        if(self.delegate)
        [self.delegate setVisualIndicatorColor:[PassportScanner getColorForFraction:0.5]];

        while (rotatedRegions[0].height + rotatedRegions[0].y >= rotated.rows) {
            rotatedRegions[0].height--;
        }

        image1 = rotated(rotatedRegions[0]);

        while (rotatedRegions[1].height + rotatedRegions[1].y >= rotated.rows) {
            rotatedRegions[1].height--;
        }

        image2 = rotated(rotatedRegions[1]); //**——>Problem starts here**

        //More code
```

}

I have looked at these links but none of them helped me solve the problem:
[Error with OpenCV ROI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712057/error-with-opencv-roi)
[OpenCv assertion failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248611/opencv-assertion-failed)

Comment: Print to console your rotated regions (0 and 1) rectangle parameters and check if values are correct.

Comment: Debug the `rotatedRegions[1]` values (x, y, width, height) and make sure, the rect lies completely inside `rotated` Mat